# Is there a character limit on passwords for Expression Engine?

Tags: password

I've run into an issue I've never seen before regarding a password that appears to be too long. Is there a character limit to passwords?

The client has been using a simple password generator that creates passwords like 'RoadFrame21Bubbles', however a recent password seems to be causing issues, it's 33 characters long and not really different from the format above apart from it's length.

I've tried a shorter password and it works.

The client is reluctant to change this password for their user as they have sent out letters showing the password/user name already.

Any help is appreciated on this.

Answer (score 1):

How were these users added to the system?

As far as I can tell there is no maximum length although the input fields both in the CP and the CP login specify 40 maximum characters. So if they were created the "normal way" in the CP then this shouldn't be an issue (just use the first 40 chars in the pwd to log in).

If they were created programatically then there might be issues though, not sure..

Comment: The usernames and passwords were created from the 'Register Member' page in the CP. The passwords would have been generated automatically and pasted in.

Comment: Ok, so any passwords created there will work on the frontend as well. Make sure you don't have a char limit on the input field.